# Why do occur lazyInitializationException with @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have to entities as follows:

```
public class FeatureType {
   @Id Sring id;
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="featureType", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   List<Metadata> entities = new ArrayList();
}

public class Metadata{
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   FeatureType featureType;
}
```

Now, the `featureType` repository is as follow:

```
@Repository
public interface FeatureTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<FeatureType, String> 
{}
```

I created a String to FeatureType converter as follows:

```
class StringToFeatureType implement Converter<String, FeatureType>
{
   private FeatureTypeRepsitory rep;
   public StringToFeatureType(FeatureTypeRepsitory rep){this.rep = rep;}
   @Override
   public FeatureType convert(String name)
   {
       return rep.findByIdOrNull(name);
   }
}
```

I have a problem in controller:

```
@RestController
public FeatureTypeController()
{
   @Transactional
   @GetMapping("/featureType-{featureType}/metadata")
   List<Metadata> getMetadata(FeatureType featureType)
   {
      system.out.println(entityManager.contains(featureType));//print false
      system.out.println(featureType.getMetadata().size());//Occur Error here
      return featureType.getMetadata();
   }
}
```

I have Opened transaction, But when the programe receive to line `system.out.println(featureType.getMetadata().size());`, Occur exception as follows:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role: fava.FeatureType.metadata, could not initialize
>   proxy - no session

I know if featurType has some metadata, the problem occure error in serialization, but eccure error at line `system.out.println(featureType.getMetadata().size())`. What's porblem?

Comment: Making your web-layer is a bad thing imho. That being said your `@Transactional` has no effect on the `FeatureType` you pass into the method. It is loaded outside of a transaction as the converter executes as part of the reques thandling, Only when the actual method is being called the transaction will be started.

Comment: @M.Deinum `@Transaction` open in converter then closed and then open in controller, Where is the problem?

Comment: As you state, you have 2 transactions... The transaction and thus entitymanager you originally used isn't available anymore...

Comment: @M.Deinum and solution? Unuse spring converter?

Comment: May be because `featureType` object is in `transient` cycle but not `persistent`.

Comment: Either attach it to the entitymanager again, or don't use a converter. I would suggest the later and do that in a service as that is where it belongs imho. Then make the service transactional and not your web-layer.